# boost::program_options space in config file

Tags: c++, boost, configuration-files, boost-program-options

I want to set options to my parser program via simple config file parsed by `boost::program_options`. I want to set `prefixmiddle` to  (single space).

I already tried that options:

```
prefixmiddle= 
prefixmiddle=" " # Equals to `" "`
prefixmiddle = " " # Same
prefixmiddle =
```

Is there a way to do it?

P.S. Of course, I can always use `""` and remove them, but I wonder if there is another solution.

Comment: Digging in history, i found and [old issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/850) which resulted in a patch that introduced the current behavior you describe. | If this is a one-off, I'd just strip the quotes myself after processing the config. Otherwise, you might wanna check out [validators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.31.6.7) or perhaps even [`value_semantic`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/program_options/reference.html#header.boost.program_options.value_semantic_hpp) and friends. Those assume you have a custom type tho.

Comment: Or perhaps use a [notifier function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#id-1_3_31_9_10_1_1_7_5_6-bb) that strips the quotes and updates the member variable, rather than directly binding the `typed_value` to the member.